# Flutter - change fill color of datatable checkbox

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to change the background color of the datatable's checkboxes.

**Exemple**

I want to go from this:

[image]

to this (it's a drawing):

[image]

Is it possible to change it from theme?

**EDIT 1:**

I already tried **checkboxTheme**, It will only change the border from white to my color. But I just want to change the fill color.

my checkbox theme is:

```
CheckboxThemeData(fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color?>((Set<MaterialState> states) {
    if (states.contains(MaterialState.selected))
        return primaryColor;
    return null;
})),
```

But my datatable's checkbox still blue while Checkbox's widget changed color...
[image]

(the bottom's checkbox is from checkbox widget, for comparison)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an attempt to recreate the checkbox theme:

```dart
CheckboxThemeData(
  side: MaterialStateBorderSide.resolveWith(
      (_) => const BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.blue)),
  fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red),
  checkColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.white),
),
```

Try it out using:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool checked = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
        checkboxTheme: CheckboxThemeData(
          side: MaterialStateBorderSide.resolveWith(
              (_) => const BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.blue)),
          fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red),
          checkColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Checkbox(
            value: checked,
            onChanged: (b) {
              setState(() {
                checked = b ?? false;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

Edit: After doing some digging, I found that the `DataTable` uses `ThemeData.colorScheme.primary` as the fill color.

Try this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool checked = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
        colorScheme: ThemeData.light().colorScheme.copyWith(
              onPrimary: Colors.white, // Color for checkmark in datatable
              primary: Colors.red, // Color used for checkbox fill in datatable
            ),
        checkboxTheme: CheckboxThemeData(
          side: MaterialStateBorderSide.resolveWith(
              (_) => const BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.blue)),
          fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red),
          checkColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: DataTable(
          columns: const [
            DataColumn(label: Text('Checkbox')),
          ],
          rows: [
            DataRow(
              selected: checked,
              onSelectChanged: (b) {
                setState(() {
                  checked = b ?? false;
                });
              },
              cells: const [
                DataCell(Text('hi')),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! :) This code work when I use Checkbox's Widget.
but in my case, I use datatable, and checkbox is automatically added to my datarow. 
But I don't know why, the fill color don't want to change... only the border. 

The checkboxes appear when I use the following property: onSelectChanged.

Probably because I'm on Flutter desktop (from Linux)

Comment: I just tried it out using a datatable, and like you said, the fill color is not being set by the `CheckBoxThemeData`. I'm not sure at the moment how to solve this, but I'll let you know if I come up with something.